# Issue with $headers (From:)

Tags: php, email, contact-form

My code is this:

```
<?php
$name = $_POST['name'];
$email = $_POST['email'];
$messagesubject = $_POST['subject'];
$text = $_POST['text'];

$to = "name@email.com";
$subject = 'Message from a site visitor '.$name;

$content = 'Name: '.$name."\r\n";
$content .= 'E-mail: '.$email."\r\n";
$content .= 'Subject: '.$messagesubject."\r\n";
$content .= 'Message: '.$text."\r\n";

$headers .= 'From: '.$field_email."\r\n";
$headers .= 'Reply-To: '.$field_email."\r\n";
"; 

$send_contact=mail($to,$subject,$headers,$content);

if($send_contact){
echo "Thank you!";
}
else {
echo "ERROR";
}
?>
```

I receive a mail but on the senders address (From) is written my e-mail address from the hosting server. If i add $headers ( i created the headers like this: `$headers = 'From: '.$field_email."\r\n"; ")` in the `mail()` than i don't receive any mail...

what do i do wrong? Im a begginer in this

Comment: Show us the whole code including what doesn't work

Comment: can You try headers from manual just to check whether it works? $headers = 'From: webmaster@example.com' . "\r\n" .
    'Reply-To: webmaster@example.com' . "\r\n" .
    'X-Mailer: PHP/' . phpversion();
and see if that changes anything.

Comment: @JohnConde i reedited my post...

Comment: If that's Your exact code than You have a problem right after $headers .= 'Reply-To: '.$field_email."\r\n"; You need to remove this-> ";

Comment: @Mati i tried it and now i get in the body of the mail : From: webmaster@example.com
Reply-To: webmaster@example.com
X-Mailer: PHP/5.4.24    but nothing else... no subject or email or message from the form anymore...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, as manual says ( http://php.net/manual/en/function.mail.php ) mail function variables go like this:

```
mail($to, $subject, $message, $headers);
```

and Your looks like that:

```
mail($to, $subject, $headers, $message);
```

switch it and You should get what You want :)

Comment: wait, step by step:
1. Are You providing Your email in $to variable?
2. Are all variables You've posted correct? I mean if they exists, and there is no spelling error?
3. Do You get message "ERROR" at the end?

Comment: i copied without looking this code above again, and forgot to change my mail address. ups... i get not the email but still the body is: From:
Reply-To:    and nothing else... i was putting correct variables...

Comment: i have no idea why... but if i let the headers on 3rd place... i get an email... if i put it on last position it sais it was sent but i dont get the mail...:)) really strange...

Answer (score 0):

A valid From: header in an email must contain a valid email address:

`From: <someone@somewhere.xxx>`

Note the encloseing brackets. You may also add additional text:

`From: Someone Important <someone@somewhere.xxx>`